# jquery.js doesn't get loaded in Tomcat

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

OK, so I found out so far, that despite me having the jquery.js file in the same folder as the jsp file I have, the Ecipse-Tomcat configuration is executing the files in a different location and it takes all the files except for jquery.js How is this possible and how I can make it automatically load the file in it execution folder?

In my case jquery refuses to work unless I specifically put it in the folder where tomcat is executing the files... Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: when you ask a question be more specific

Comment: What is your code of `JSP` ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Well in this case it wasn't about the code at all. The code was all fine, it was eclipse/tomcats fault they weren't compiling well and putting all files together where they're supposed to belong to. I didn't want to put unnecessary code if it wasn't related to my question.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani there's no need to show code in this question.

Comment: @ArturasM you should not have javascript nor css files in the same folder of your HTML or JSP web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after a few hours of struggling, I finally found a solution to this problem. Seems Eclipse Tomcat probably isn't refreshing and checking the files in the path well if you're using any other perspective than Java EE. In my case I was using and working all the time in the normal Java perspective and this way it never reloaded even when I would click refresh. Now however I switched to Java EE view and clicked refresh. The file finally appeared and jquery finally started working!

Answer (score 1):

All JS/CSS/HTML files are static resources and would be served from Tomcat through [DefaultServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html). You would need to configure the default servlet in your web.xml with appropriate location to the folder where these are present. This has nothing to do with the location of JSP, though the JSPs can also go under the same folder.